# What Happened 12/30/17 Last Recieved Transaction into Bitcoin Core Wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, security, wallet.dat

I have found a different receiving address within my wallet that is not mine... at least I did not create it. It seems to me that all of my transactions are now going to this new address instead of into my wallet. is there anything that I can do to recover these missing or stolen transactions?

In the debug log file on 1/1/18 I found that Bitcoin 12.0 was restarted and this shortly after, among other things:

`InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1`

Seems like someone got in and redirected my transactions. Am I paranoid or did I just get robbed?

Answer (score 1):

> I have found a different receiving address within my wallet that is not mine.

If it is in your wallet then by definition it is yours (unless you added it as a watch-only address which I doubt in this case).

It could be a change address, automatically generated by your wallet to receive change from another transaction you sent. Without more info it is hard to say though.

The `-whitelistforcerelay=1` parameter is nothing to worry about, that only relates to the relay of blocks between peers and is nothing to do with your transactions or wallet.

Comment: I'm not sure but if it is "mine" as part of my wallet then I should still receive the mining transactions into my wallet periodically.... I tried to "choose" between the receiving addresses and could not.  If it is a change address then I would think that I would see the transactions within the wallet, but there is no evidence of activity for any address.... I am just not sure how to fix the problem.....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "mining transactions". Can you see the transactions in your wallet? You said you found them in your wallet, you seem to be contradicting yourself

Comment: I found the different receiving addresses under the file tab in my Bitcoin core wallet.... there are sending and receiving addresses found there. As far as any transactions... the last one was on 12/30/17 and there has not been any since. prior to 12/30/17 transaction were received into my wallet about every 3 or 4 days from the mining equipment that I have.

Comment: In the debug window of Bitcoin Core under the information tab, I see that the "current number of transactions" within the memory pool is active and growing in number which tells me that my mining equipment is functioning and "processing" bitcoin transactions.

Comment: No, you are probably not mining, the number of transactions in the mempool grows because you are connected to the network. To mine you need specialized hardware

Comment: Well, I spent 1500 bucks on a mining machine that is still running with good and active connections to the network it just seems to be making money for someone else at the moment.. I don't know what's wrong that is why I am on here but I'm about to unplug it and move on.

Comment: Well yes if you have a miner then you will need to configure it to pay you, typically you mine for a pool and then the pool will pay you, make sure you set up your configuration correctly.

Comment: That is what I don't understand, It has been configured correctly and has been working with no issues for over a year and now all of the sudden has quit... I have not changed anything or done anything to alter the original configuration.... one day it's working, the next it's not.

Comment: @user80788 If you set everything up yourself you should make some checks. Check the mining pool configuration if you use one, ensure that it is paying to your address. Same thing with the miner. If someone else set it up for you then that could be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

usually if your bitcoin was send to the wrong address, you can try undo it while it in the mempool but if it already added to the blockchain then u cant undo it.

this may causes by a virus i used to have where i copy an address and it just made an completely random address.